# PHP pow function not working as expected

Tags: php, pow

How is it possible to create a doubling function?

I have a start value `50` and I have an `x` value of 3 as in the following example. I would like to get the following result:

```
y = 50 * 2 ^ 3 = 400.
```

But if I write the following code in PHP I get 1000000 as the result:

```
$y = pow(50 * 2 , 3);
```

How do I write this this power function properly in PHP?

Comment: `pow(50 * 2 , 3);` equals to `pow(100, 3)` i.e 100 * 100 * 100. Learn math.

Comment: thanks ... haha, nice comment "learn math". I cant get it in my head sometimes .. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

(You just wrote it in  the wrong order)

```
echo $y = 50 * pow(2 , 3);
```

Output:

```
400
```

Your old code:

```
$y = pow(50 * 2 , 3); //Same as: $y = pow(100 , 3); and this means: 100 * 100 * 100
```

Comment: Small addition: you were calculating (50*2)³ by using pow(50 * 2 , 3)

Comment: Sorry I meant the original question calculated (50*2)³ instead of 50*2³

Comment: I think that @ByteHamster was referring to the original question, and was suggesting an addendum to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$y = 50*(pow(2, 3))
```

You was doing something like "(50*2)^3=100^3= 100*100*100"

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are asking how to create a 'doubling function.' In your example it would seem that you are starting with 50 and multiplying that times the cube of 2, as in:

`50 * ( 2 ^ 3) = 50 * 8 = 400`.

In PHP 4, PHP 5, and PHP 7 **pow** is an Exponential expression, meaning 'to the power of.'

Usage:  `number pow ( number $base , number $exp )`

It returns the base raised to the power of the exponent.

In your case, you could write:

```
$x = 3;  // You indicated x was equal to 3
$y = 50 * pow(2 , $x);
echo $y; // Should display 400 as a result
```